# File Handling, Writing, Reading

Tags: python, file, error-handling

I stumbled across an issue of file handling, 
*second line* gives you an value of 9 for no reason,
*third line* gives an Error io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

```
c = open("Test.txt", "w+")
c.write("Hey there")
content = c.read()
c.close

print (content)
```

*How can I solve this ?*

Comment: Result of line 2: what do the docs say `write()` returns? Error: what do the docs say `open(<path>, "w+")` does? Do you use an IDE? Does it show doc strings when you hover over a function name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Second Line gives you an value of 9 for no reason

That is the return value from the [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) function in Python 3. The value is the number of characters written to the file.

> Third Line gives an Error io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Not sure what you've done here. Following the `write()`, the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file. If you really opened the file with `w+` then you should not see an error, but 0 characters should be read from the file. If you opened the file with mode `w`, then you would get the `io.UnsupportedOperation` exception because the file is not opened for reading. Check which mode you used when you tested.

Try this:

```
with open('Test.txt', 'w+') as c:
    n = c.write("Hey there")
    print('Wrote {} characters to file'.format(n))

    content = c.read()
    print('Read {} characters from file'.format(len(content)))
    print('{!r}'.format(content))

    _ = c.seek(0)    # move file pointer back to the start of the file
    content = c.read()
    print('After seeking to start, read {} characters from file'.format(len(content)))
    print('{!r}'.format(content))
```

Output:

```
Wrote 9 characters to file
Read 0 characters from file
''
After seeking to start, read 9 characters from file
'Hey there'
```