# Save file without FileDialog in Python:Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a Notepad-style program in Python, and am stuck just on the part where clicking Save after opening a file is able to save the file without presenting a SaveAs FileDialog to the user. Using the code below, I am getting an error, "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file", being caused by the FileSave() function at the line "filename.write(data)".

Code is as below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

global filename
filename = ''

form = Tk()
form.geometry('1000x600')
form.title('Text Editor')
frame = ttk.Frame(form, padding = "3 3 12 12")
frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
textentry = Text(frame, width = 95, height = 35)
textentry.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
textentry.focus()

def FileNew():
    global filename
    textentry.delete('1.0','end')
    filename = ''

def FileOpen():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(mode = 'r')
    if filename != None:
        t = filename.read()
        textentry.delete('0.0','end')
        textentry.insert('0.0', t)
        textentry.focus()
        filename.close()

def FileSave():
    global filename
    if filename == '':
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode = 'w')
    if filename != None:
        data = textentry.get('1.0','end')
        filename.write(data)
        filename.close

def FileSaveAs():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode = 'w')
    FileSave()

btnNew = ttk.Button(frame, text = 'New', command = FileNew)
btnNew.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'S')
btnOpen = ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Open', command = FileOpen)
btnOpen.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = 'S')
btnSave = ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Save', command = FileSave)
btnSave.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = 'S')
btnSaveAs = ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Save As', command = FileSaveAs)
btnSaveAs.grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = 'S')

form.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is `filename` intended to be a string of the file's name/location, or the file handle?

Comment: `filename` is supposed to be a string of the file's location. Have I got that mixed up somewhere and set it as a handle instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `askopenfile` and `asksaveasfile` return handles, which they would have to be if you're accessing attributes of `filename` like `write` and `close` in various places (plus a `filename.close` without parentheses in `fileSave`).

Comment: @JaceG *"to be a string of the file's location"*: Change to `.askopenfilename(...`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm sorry, I'm still trying to figure out Python. I'm a lot better at PHP... What would I need to change?

Comment: @stovfl Changing to that has just given me quite a long list of errors.

Comment: What do you expect `filename.read()`, `filename.write()` and `filename.close()` to do if `filename` is a string?

Comment: The string representing a file's name/location and a file handle that represents access to the file are two completely different things, but you're only using one variable to work with both. What I usually do is use the `...name` (e.g. `askopenfilename`) variants exclusively, and then manually open the file whenever I want to work with it (using a `with` block).

Comment: @JaceG: Read [file-handling-writing-reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034400/file-handling-writing-reading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your code a little bit and now everything seems to work fine for me. You can now open any .txt file and save changes to it without invoking the dialog box. I have removed `file.close()` statements from your code to achieve this.

- If you try to save a blank screen as file, your `filename` will always be equal to `''` and thus you will end up at the dialog box.
- If, however, you open up a certain file with open, you will be able to use save without invoking dialog box, because now your `filename='name of the file that you decided to open'`.

`filename.close()` statements would get in the way though, because you can't save anything into a closed file... In this case, if you use `file_open()` function with `filename.close()` statement in it, the computer will throw errors back at you since you can't save anything into a closed file.

Note: save function in your program will actually add all data from your textentry to the file and not entirely do what save is supposed to do (just add new data). You may want to work on this a little more.

I hope this helps and here's your code with a little bit of editting:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = ''

form = Tk()
form.geometry('1000x600')
form.title('Text Editor')
frame = ttk.Frame(form, padding="3 3 12 12")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
textentry = Text(frame, width=95, height=35)
textentry.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
textentry.focus()


def file_new():
    global filename
    textentry.delete('1.0', 'end')
    filename = ''


def file_open():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r+')
    if filename is not None:
        t = filename.read()
        textentry.delete('0.0', 'end')
        textentry.insert('0.0', t)
        textentry.focus()


def file_save():
    global filename
    if filename == '':
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
    if filename is not None:
        data = textentry.get('1.0', 'end')
        filename.write(data)


def file_save_as():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
    file_save()


btnNew = ttk.Button(frame, text='New', command=file_new)
btnNew.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='S')
btnOpen = ttk.Button(frame, text='Open', command=file_open)
btnOpen.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='S')
btnSave = ttk.Button(frame, text='Save', command=file_save)
btnSave.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='S')
btnSaveAs = ttk.Button(frame, text='Save As', command=file_save_as)
btnSaveAs.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='S')

form.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow that's fantastic... thanks :) I've just tried it all out and works fine! I didn't include all my code, as there's a few extra things that weren't relevant, so I've combined everything and it's going great. Extra stuff was just things like showing the current filename in the title bar, for example... just little extras here and there :)

Comment: I am so glad this could help you out. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Oh, and as a helpful note, comparison with None value should be done like this: If myVar is not None: I din't include this in my post, but you were doing this with comparison operator != and I changed that as well.